# rectangles in UIView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have created a rectangle like this in objective -c :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 440, 320, 30));

}
```

in the view controller i have created a function which then calls this rectangle and an animation block so it looks like its coming out by the alpha command :

```
PopUpRectangle *RectangeView = [[PopUpRectangle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 538, 320, 30)];
RectangeView.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:RectangeView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                 animations:^ {
                     RectangeView.alpha = 1;
                 }];
```

I have a function that is triggered by an event and then I call the above code to create the rectangle on the screen.

but how do i revert the action, would it be best to create another rectangle which brings the alpha back to 0 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a local reference to `RectangeView` so you when you want you can animate it back out, and remove it from the view.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
             animations:^ {
                 RectangeView.alpha = 0;
             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 [RectangleView removeFromSuperview];
             }];
```

Comment: brill adam, but how would i create a local reference to RectangleView ? As its in a UIView .m file ?

Comment: Save it as a property or instance variable in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could also move your animation block to it's own function.

Like the other comment suggests save a local reference to it so that you can access it later.

```
- (void)animateBlock{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
         animations:^ {
             RectangeView.alpha = !RectangleView.alpha; //Reverse the current alpha 
         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [RectangleView removeFromSuperview];
         }];
}
```